# Converting String to Hashmap with comma

Tags: java, android, regex, hashmap

I wanna convert a string back to hashmap. It works fine in most cases, but it crashes when the string has a comma in the middle. Here's my method:

```
protected HashMap<String,String> convertToStringToHashMap(String text){
    text=text.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", "");
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] entrySetValues = text.split(",");

    for(String str : entrySetValues){
        String[] arr = str.trim().split("=",-1);
        hm.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
    return hm;
}
```

Sample string:

```
"company=A Sample Company, Inc."
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How would you expect to represent keys containing `=`, or anything with braces and commas in? Fundamentally you're likely to end up with something a bit like JSON by the time you've added escaping... at which point I'd just use a JSON API.

Comment: in short you can't do it 100% . no matter how good you parse the string, there are still some cases that break ur program. but if you make some assumption regarding input then its possible. e.g(your key and values never going to have "=" in them

Comment: yep. I go with cleaning my input before passing it. this is the only solution I can think of for now. thanks anyway. :)